# stax-ex-1.8.jar is not found in location, javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, spring-boot, many-to-many

> i want create a login app using springboot security jpa hibernate. So
>   i have added role class with user class(both are entity classes).
>   Earlier when i have wrote code for registration page it worked. Today
>   when i wrote code and try to run this application it is giving some
>   errors in console
>
> //my console is...

The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\A.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.4.0-b180830.0438\jaxb-runtime-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar,file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/txw2-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar,file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar,file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/stax-ex-1.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar,file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
     \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

```
2019-03-29 12:53:15.754  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.StudentEnrollmentApplication         : Starting StudentEnrollmentApplication on A-PC with PID 3032 (C:\Users\A\Desktop\STS\spring-jsp\target\classes started by A in C:\Users\A\Desktop\STS\spring-jsp)
2019-03-29 12:53:15.835  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.StudentEnrollmentApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-29 12:53:15.954  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-03-29 12:53:15.954  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-03-29 12:53:18.504  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-03-29 12:53:18.715  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 190ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
2019-03-29 12:53:19.876  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d563f7eb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-03-29 12:53:21.233  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-03-29 12:53:21.320  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-29 12:53:21.320  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2019-03-29 12:53:21.369  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\JAVA\jre1.8.0_202\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\A\Downloads\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.7.RELEASE;;.]
2019-03-29 12:53:22.178  WARN 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar] from classloader hierarchy

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\A\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.4.0-b180830.0438\jaxb-api-2.4.0-b180830.0359.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:266) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) [tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.application.StudentEnrollmentApplication.main(StudentEnrollmentApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]

2019-03-29 12:53:22.181  WARN 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.4.0-b180830.0438/txw2-2.4.0-b180830.0438.jar] from classloader hierarchy
2019-03-29 12:53:22.220  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-03-29 12:53:22.229  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-29 12:53:22.230  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6276 ms
2019-03-29 12:53:22.853  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-03-29 12:53:23.167  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-03-29 12:53:23.285  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2019-03-29 12:53:23.457  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
2019-03-29 12:53:23.769  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-03-29 12:53:24.112  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2019-03-29 12:53:24.680  WARN 3032 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
2019-03-29 12:53:24.682  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-03-29 12:53:24.693  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-03-29 12:53:24.698  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-29 12:53:24.726  INFO 3032 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-29 12:53:24.730 ERROR 3032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.application.StudentEnrollmentApplication.main(StudentEnrollmentApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: role, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

> //User entity class

```
package com.application.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;
    @Transient
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user-role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;


    public User(Long id, String username, String password, String passwordConfirm, Set<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



}
```

> //Role entity class

```
package com.application.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<User> users;
    public Role(Long id, String name, Set<User> users) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }



}
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException ... what do you think it indicates?

Comment: the perticular file is missing in this following location. but how can i add this jar in this location? i have added this jar in my pom.xml but it dosen't resolve at all

Comment: did you re-build your code? did you get an error? have you checked your repository? if need be, clean your repository, build again and try

Comment: after rebuild i got build success.

Comment: adding a dependency to your pom.xml only get you so far. It's the actual build of the project that 'll download any missing dependencies and that 'll check if everything needed is present.

Comment: same error occurred again in console

Comment: ok i am post my pom. xml file

Comment: what do you mean, in console?

Comment: stax-ex-1.8.jar is not found in location, javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar (The system cannot find the file specified) it is ocurred. it didn't resolve.